# How to set fixed height for background image in HTML using css and the width should follow the device width

Tags: html, css

I am in a situation where I need my bg image to be of the fixed height and the width of the image should vary on device width change. The image should crop according to the device width and whenever the device width increases the width of the image should also increase.
Let's take a scenario where I have an image of width 2000px and the first device it is being viewed is of 1200px then the image should be cropped from both the side i.e. from left 2000-400=1600px and from right 1600-400=1200 and this is how the image should fix in the background.
Now if the device width increases the height should always be fixed for example the height of the image is 200px and width is 2000px and it is being viewed on the device having 1000px of with then the image should be of the fixed height and the width should vary as stated above.

Comment: Just give a static height:200px; Then control de width with media queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with following CSS

```
background-image: url('bg.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: top center;
```

Answer (score 0):

Put image in background centered and width background size cover:

```
div {
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
  background:url('http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-1920-1850-9.jpg') no-repeat center;
  background-size:cover;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mn7e0u12/

In this way your image is cut and resized by the container.

Comment: There is a background color also which needs to be filled in the background. If I set the height property as 200px the color is only filled for 200px. How to overcome that please help.

Comment: Use another div that contain this with image and apply background color to external div.